# changing imageviews on changing combobox JAVA FX

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, imageview

i am working on some project, the problem i am facing is, that i have a combobox and one imageview, the images on imageviews change according to the selection of combox box values, however i managed to achieve some functionality, currently, whenever i change the the value of combo box the image views changes correctly, but on the second change the imageview remains same.

here is my code

```
 fn.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Object t, Object t1) {
            if (t1 != null) {
                System.out.println("here");
                for (int i = 0; i < Fid.size(); i++) {
                    String getAllFines = "SELECT * FROM fines WHERE fine_id='" + Fid.get(i) + "'";
                    ResultSet rs1 = handler.execQuery(getAllFines);
                    try {
                        if (rs1.next()) {
                            System.out.println("here fine name is " + Fid.get(i));

                            InputStream is = rs1.getBinaryStream("fine_image");
                            BufferedImage imBuff = ImageIO.read(is);
                            image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(imBuff, null);
                            imageView.setImage(image);
                        }
                    } catch (SQLException | IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(UpdateFinesFXMLController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

here `fid` `observablelist` is the `id`, on the basis of that query i am getting the images from database.

Comment: What's `fn`? Post a [mcve]. You probably don't need a change listener.

Comment: fn is my combobox

Comment: why i dont need change listener

Comment: Because you can bind. Post a [mcve].

Comment: Why do you expect the contents of `Fid` to be modified between the calls? Your code loads EVERY image corresponding to an id in the list keeping the last one... Also `Image` has an constructor loading from a `InputStream` directly; There should be no need to make the detour to `BufferedImage`...

Comment: than how can i do this?

Comment: i printed `FID` the content of `FID` changes during `onChange`, like i have the `id's` 7, 8, and 9, i want to show imageview of each corresponding `id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

somehow, i managed to resolve my issue, changes i have made,  i removed the looping in `onChange` method, and i have get the `id` from the `onChange` method parameter, because on that parameter i have the value of current item, and all goes good, the problem was with `loop`.

here is my resolve

```
 fn.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Object t, Object t1) {
            try {
                System.out.println(t1);
                String getAllFines1 = "SELECT * FROM fines WHERE fine_name='" + t1 + "'";
                ResultSet rs1 = handler.execQuery(getAllFines1);
                while (rs1.next()) {
                    InputStream is = rs1.getBinaryStream("fine_image");
                    BufferedImage imBuff = ImageIO.read(is);
                    image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(imBuff, null);
                    imageView.setImage(image);
                }

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(UpdateFinesFXMLController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(UpdateFinesFXMLController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });
```